# How to highlight main label for checkbox input using css or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Let's assume i have code like below;

```
  <div>       
    <span>SELECT1</span>          
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" value="option1" name="option1">
          <span>option1</span>  
        </div>   
        <div>     
          <input type="checkbox" value="option2" name="option2">
          <span>option2</span>     
        </div>
       <span>SELECT2</span>          
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" value="option3" name="option3">
          <span>option3</span>  
        </div>   
        <div>     
          <input type="checkbox" value="option4" name="option4">
          <span>option4</span>     
        </div>
   </div>
```

Is there a way to highlight related "SELECT1" or "SELECT2" if at least one of involved option has checked ? In my situation , it is ok to do so for labels options1,2 and option3,4  however, how for SELECT1 and SELECT2 using css or jquery/js ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it quite easily:

```js
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    if($('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')){
    $('.title').css('color','red');
    }
    else{
    $('.title').css('color','black');
    }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>       
     
    
           <span class="title">SELECT</span>          
                <div>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="option1" name="option1">
                  <span>option1</span>  
                </div>   
                <div>     
                  <input type="checkbox" value="option2" name="option2">
                  <span>option2</span>     
                </div>
           </div>
```

Comment: what about if i use multiple headers such as SELECT2 SELECT3 and so on ?